# Angular 2 AOT build producing sourcemaps inline AND in a file

Tags: angular, gulp, rollupjs, angular2-aot

I'm working on a production build for an Angular 2 application and am attempting to use the Angular 2 AoT build process to reduce package size (documented [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html))

I got the build working via the aot compiler CLI and rollup CLI, and i'm getting the output i'm expecting. **My bundle.js file is ~2k.** and there's an accompanying source map file. YAY!

Next, I attempted to incorporate rollup into my existing gulp build. Everything works *except* that the source map is inlined in the bundle making it **over 2MB.** Additionally, a source map file is generated as well. When i manually delete the inline source map, my bundle size goes down to the ~2k.

My question is how do I get my bundle.js to be generated without the inline source map?

Things I've tried: Searching SO, scouring the [Angular2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html), the [rollup-stream docs](https://github.com/permutatrix/rollup-stream), and the [gulp-sourcemap docs](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps). I haven't found anything that addresses this issue specifically.

Below are the pertinent config files

**AoT-specific tsconfig file** (tsconfig-aot.json):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "es2015",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
   "removeComments": false,
   "noImplicitAny": true,
   "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
   "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

**rollup config** (i've tried commenting out the dest and sourceMapFile file paths to see if that was throwing gulp off, but it had no effect):

```
import rollup from 'rollup';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

let config = {
    entry: 'app/app-aot.js',
    dest: 'wwwroot/dist/bundle.js', // output a single application bundle
    sourceMap: true,
    sourceMapFile: 'wwwroot/dist/bundle.js.map',
    format: 'iife',
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
        commonjs({
            include: ['node_modules/rxjs/**']
        }),
        uglify()
    ]
}

//paths are relative to the execution path
export default config
```

And the **gulp file**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var helpers = require('./config/helpers');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var rollup = require('rollup-stream');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var sourcemap = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var paths = {
    app: helpers.root('app/**/*'),
    bootstrap: helpers.root('app/assets/bootstrap/'),
    images: helpers.root('app/assets/images/')
};

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del(['wwwroot/**/*']);
});

gulp.task('clean-aot', ['clean'], function() {
    return del(['aot/**/*']);
});

gulp.task('bundle-aot', ['clean', 'clean-aot'], function(callBack) {
    exec('\"node_modules/.bin/ngc\" -p tsconfig-aot.json', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        callBack(err);
    });
});

gulp.task('bundle-rollup', ['bundle-aot'], function() {
    return rollup('rollup-config.js')
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemap.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(sourcemap.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist'));
});

gulp.task('bundle-copy-files', ['bundle-rollup'], function() {
    var bsCss = gulp.src(paths.bootstrap + '/css/*.min.css').pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/assets/bootstrap/css/'));
    var bsFonts = gulp.src(paths.bootstrap + '/fonts/*').pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/assets/bootstrap/fonts/'));
    var images = gulp.src(paths.images + '*').pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/assets/images/'));
    var shim = gulp.src('node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js').pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/'));
    var zone = gulp.src('node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js').pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/'));
    var index = gulp.src('app/index-aot.html').pipe(rename('index.html')).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/'));

    return merge(bsCss, bsFonts, images, shim, zone, index);
});

gulp.task('bundle', ['clean', 'clean-aot', 'bundle-aot', 'bundle-rollup', 'bundle-copy-files']);
```

**Edit:** I did find a workaround by having gulp execute rollup with the CLI. I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong in the gulp or rollup config though.

```
gulp.task('bundle-rollup', ['bundle-aot'], function(callBack) {

    exec('\"node_modules/.bin/rollup\" -c rollup-config.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        callBack(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to change your `"sourceMap": false` in your tsconfig.json like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "es2015",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "sourceMap": false,          /// <<< This is the change you need
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
   "removeComments": false,
   "noImplicitAny": true,
   "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
   "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```